Do spells taken by the Magic Initiate feat require material components that cost gold?
Good afternoon, I have a question about the Magic Initiate feat.
I am a cleric, I chose the cleric spell Ceremony, however this ritual requires a material component that has a cost (25 gp worth of powdered silver).
Do I need this material component to cast this spell with the Magic Initiate feat?

Welcome to the stack! I took the liberty of reformulating your question's body so that the title and the body ask it in the same way, for better clarity in the answers.

It is not clear to me why you took a spell that is already in your list via the Magic Initiate feat.

@Eddymage A slight abuse of the game mechanics, if you take the backgrounds Astral Drifter, it gives feat Magic initiate, but forces you to choose the cleric spell.
And this allows you to always have a spell prepared that does not fill up slots.

Yes, they do.
The part about getting a spell says:

In addition, choose one 1st-level spell to learn from that same list. Using this feat, you can cast the spell once at its lowest level, and you must finish a long rest before you can cast it in this way again.

All it does it gives you a spell known and an ability to cast it using the feat instead of your Spellcasting feature, thus without expanding a slot (because slots are part of the Spellcasting or Pact Magic ability).
Because there are no hidden rules, properties of the spell, including material components, stay unchanged.

A bit tangential, I question the wisdom of burning a feat on the Ceremony spell, or even its existence in the first place. You already have it, and you don't really need it anyway:

Creating Holy Water is something Cleric or Paladin can do without this spell, for the same cost.
Prevention of becoming undead is cheaper using other spells like Gentle Repose.
Reversing alignment change is a common adventure hook and breaking it for DMs is something I don't get.
Other things works only once.


This is what still interests me, do I cast the entire spell through feat, as stated in the rules, or not?
As an example, some races can cast spells due to their characteristics, such as the Drow can cast Darkness, it does not require them to have material components, right?
Is there such a hidden rule in this case as well?
This is precisely the reason why I initially took the Ceremony, because I thought that I would have the opportunity to use it as a “free” analogue of creating holy water, as well as a source of Blessing for 24 hours

@LobsterN7 if a feature says that you don't need a component, then you don't. If it says nothing, normal requirements apply.

Three correct answers posted,  but I’ve only upvoted yours because you helpfully question the decision to use the feat on a spell you already have.

@LobsterN7 Like Molot said: If the ability let you ignore components, it would say so specifically. You can't get free holy water this way.  Not sure what blessing you're talking about, there's three blessing-type effects of Ceremony but they all work only once per creature EVER (except Wedding and that can only be reused if the spouse dies first which is... theoretically abusable I guess, depending on how wildly evil your party is).

@DarthPseudonym Oh right, I didn't notice that these blessings only work once, damn

@Darth Pseudonym Depending on how you view killing and resurrecting a willing spouse for a +2 AC, the party might not need to be evil at all.

@Grooke If you rez your previous spouse I don't think you're a widow(er), so you wouldn't be able to get remarried for a new blessing, but that's maybe a question for the legal system and/or your deity.

@Mołot You obviously haven't heard about the polygamous zealot barbarian build; for most people "till death do you part" is a once-in-a-lifetime thing, for the zealot barbarian it is tuesday.

@Yakk I assume you're actually talking to me, but again, if you get rezzed then you weren't actually parted by death, were you? (It may be of note that church and state authorities have actually already grappled with whether being revived from a technically dead state in a medical setting would terminate marriages, and they've universally answered in the negative.)

Polygamous zealot barbarian requires a huge amount of buy-in from the DM. It wouldn't actually work at any table I played, as far as I can tell. This is quirky theoretical optimization and another reason I don't particularly care for this spell.

You need the components
The feat says very precisely what it allows you to do:

(…)  Using this feat, you can cast the spell once at its lowest level, and you must finish a long rest before you can cast it in this way again. (…)

There is nothing there about being able to waive the need for material components that have a cost (or any components for that matter), therefore it's not something the feat can do. It lets you cast the spell once per long rest and doesn't modify anything about that spell, if it has component requirements, you need to satisfy those.

Yes, you need material components.
The feat description does not specifies that you do not need any material component, it allows you to cast a 1st level spell at its lowest level once per day.
If you choose a spell that belongs to your class list, as in your case, you can cast it even with your spell slots.
Game features that overcome the usage of material components specify it.
For example, the Innate Spellcasting trait of many monsters explicitly says that the creature does not need nay material component. See for example the Drow Elite Warrior:

Innate Spellcasting. The drow’s spellcasting ability is Charisma (spell save DC 12). It can innately cast the following spells, requiring no material components:

